# Can energy go through higher dimensions?

Tags: energy-conservation, spacetime-dimensions

It is hypothetically predicted that gravitons can escape from the 4th dimension or brane and "leak" or go through higher dimensions. I wonder if energy can do the same thing. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: How do you define energy if you have lots of gravitons? Answer: You don't.

Comment: Theoretically everything is possible that you can dream up. That's really not the problem with gravity. The problem with gravity is that it is very hard to make measurements that take theoretical imagination to a viable hypothesis.

Comment: Gravitons obviously carry energy, you answered your own question. Unless you meant something else by 'energy'

Comment: If you are in the context of string theory, a string can extend to any dimension. A string has energy, so yes.